# Compute the total RAM used by Python dict or list

Tags: python, memory, dictionary

**My problem:**
I am writing a simple Python tool to help me visualize my data as a function of many parameters.  Each change in parameters involves a non-trivial amount of time, so I would like to cache each step's resulting imagery and supporting data in a dictionary. But then I worry that this dictionary could grow too large over time.  Most of my data is in the form of Numpy arrays.

**My question:**
How would one go about computing the total number of bytes used by a Python dictionary.  The dictionary itself may contain lists and other dictionaries, each of which contain data stored in Numpy arrays.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a memory profiler such as [PySizer](http://pysizer.8325.org/) or [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy).